# Trying to get property of non-object error using foreach in Laravel

Tags: php, foreach, laravel-5

First am new to larval, I want to get the inserted names in the database to be selected in the options field so that I wrote my code like the follwoing

```
<select class="form-control select2" name="disease[]" multiple>
<?php $diseases=DB::table('diseases')->get();?>
@if($diseases)
  @foreach($diseases as  $disease)
      <option value="{{$disease->id}}" @if(!empty($result->disease_id))
          <?php $get_disease=json_decode($result->disease_id);?>
              @foreach($get_disease as $g_d)
                   @if($g_d->id==$disease->disease_id)
                        selected="selected"
                   @endif
              @endforeach
           @endif>{{ $disease->name }}</option>
   @endforeach
 @endif
</select>
```

but by using this code I am getting an error like this `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: First of all Remove @ beacuse it hides all notices

Comment: @TarangP by removing @ also gets same error

Comment: Tell Which Error You Get

Comment: gets same error like Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: show us the error from browser which includes line numbers etc...

Comment: Try printing the $diseases variable before the if statement to see if theres anything in there. What line is throwing the error?

Comment: Please use get query in controller, then check your result via print_r or dd function, if you see your result then pass into a variable with view file and then see the result.

Comment: Sorry brothers for wasting the time i just cleared it thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You could check if $result is null before passing it to the foreach

Answer (score -1):

You should check whether the `$result` is an array or an object. If it is an array then you have to use `[]` instead of `->`.